# Facebook SDK 3.18 - replacement for the deprecated facebook constructor

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am now using the new `Facebook SDK 3.18`, i am manually checking if the native app is present or not, if app not present the open the `Webview to login`.

But the new sdk says that the its `deprecated`, but they have included the classes in the new SDK as well.

deprecated lines :

```
facebook = new Facebook("app_id");
facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            facebook.authorize(activity, PERMISSIONS,
                    Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new DialogListener() {

facebook.getAccessToken()
facebook.getAccessExpires()
```

How can  replace the above deprecated methods with the new one from the new SDK ?

I have tried and looked into but was not able to find any solution.